# Citing website only once

Tags: citing

Is there any way I can cite a website, using biblatex, without adding a new entry in the bib file, if I'm only going to cite it a single time?

Thank you in advance 
Anton

Comment: What exactly did you have in mind? Why do you not want an entry in your `.bib` file? What if you do end up having to cite the entry multiple times?

Comment: At the moment it is not really possible to cite something without an entry in the `.bib` file. The data for citations and the bibliography needs to come from a `.bib` file. Theoretically it would be possible to either create a `.bib` entry on the fly (requiring several LaTeX and Biber runs to obtain the expected result) or to fake the data internally, but while this is theoretically possible, I highly doubt that this is worth it. After all you'd have to have a way to input the data in the document as well. So you don't win a lot.